# Поиск элемента в бинарном дереве

Tags: c#, python, структуры, java, c++

Например, есть бинарное дерево, глубиной n-этажей.
Не сортированное.
Первый вариант, что пришел мне в голову, это найти нужный элемент используя рекурсивный вывод функции, т.е.:

```
struct Tree{
Tree * left;
Tree * right;
int value;
};
bool ElemSearch(Tree *root, int search_elem)
{
     if(root->value==search_elem)
         return true;
     else
     if(root->left->value==search_elem)
            return true;
     else
      if(root->right->value==search_elem)
           return true;
      else
         ElemSearch(root->left, search_val);
//и так пока не будет найден искомый элемент
}
```

В-общем, задача, избавиться от рекурсии. Как это сделать?
Если для этого нужно прочитать все дерево в какой-нибудь вектор или массив, подскажите, как это лучше сделать.
Спасибо.

Comment: Непонятно, зачем в такой задаче избавляться от рекурсии. 

Но если надо, то замените ее на while цикл.

Comment: Мне пришла в голову идея с логическими сдвигами итерационного з начения но что-то этот способ попахивает извращениями.

Comment: avp, сказали так надо.

Comment: Был сбой в у меня сети и комментарий пропал. Вставляю еще раз.

--

Непонятно, зачем в такой задаче избавляться от рекурсии. 

Но если надо, то замените ее на while цикл.

Только у Вас программка странная. IMHO

    bool search(root, elem) {
        if (!root) return false; if (root->value == elem) return true;
        if (search(root->left,elem)) return true;
        return search(root->right,elem);
    }

Ну, на самом деле я бы еще в нелокальную переменную записывал root для root->value == elem.

Но если не нравиться, преобразуйте к циклу и моделируйте стек возвратов.

Comment: Да это не программка у меня странная, это задача с собеседования такая

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробую "псевдокод"

```
bool Search (Tree *root, int elem) {
       Tree *p;

       if (!root) return false;
       initqueue();
       inqueue(root);
       while (p = getqueue()) {
         if (p->value == elem) {
            delqueue();
            return true;
         }
         if (p->left)  inqueue(p->left);
         if (p->right) inqueue(p->right);
       }
       delqueue();
       return false;
     }
```

Функции inqueue() - положить указатель в конец очереди и getqueue() - взять указатель из головы очереди или вернуть NULL, если очередь пуста, initqueue() и delqueue() IMHO сами напишите.

Что непонятно, спрашивайте.

На собеседовании можете сказать "типичная задача с очередью или обход дерева в ширину".

Comment: Ну да я понял уже примерно как эта штука работает. Т.е. если в очереди есть элементы, if анализирует на совпадение с искомым значением, иначе, при наличии детей, кидает их в очередь, и на следующей итерации уикл повторяется заново уже для детей и их детей и т.д. Спасибо Вам большое. Надо вот будет только запомнить как-нибудь).

Answer (score 0):

А что мешает дерево хранить в массиве?

Бинарное дерево будет выглядить примерно так:

корень элемент с индексом 0 (Если с 1 начинать то формулы красивее чуть чуть будут)

Его потомки (0+1) * 2 и (0+1) * 2-1

В общем случае для i-й вершины индексы потомков равны (i+1) * 2 и (i+1) * 2-1

Вершина родитель для i-й равна (i-1)/2

Если у вас дерево не будет изменяться то можно хранить сортированную копию массива (главное индексы не потерять). Восстановить путь от элемента к корню труда не составит.

Comment: почему потомки это 0*2 и 0*2+1?

Comment: и храним мы дерево не в массиве, а в динамической памяти. а там все разбросано как попало может быть (и чаще всего так и бывает).

Comment: сорри запарил чутка (сейчас исправлю), ночь на дворе

Comment: @pol500 дак вот и спрашиваю почему в массиве не хотите хранить?

Comment: дык нелья ёпт! я бы с радосью, коли можно было бы

Comment: Тогда от рекурсии вряд ли можно избавится, если только не привести к циклу, который по сути то же самое делать будет и с той же скоростью

Answer (score 0):

```
# A utility function to search a given key in BST
def search(root,key):
     
    # Base Cases: root is null or key is present at root
    if root is None or root.val == key:
        return root
 
    # Key is greater than root's key
    if root.val < key:
        return search(root.right,key)
   
    # Key is smaller than root's key
    return search(root.left,key)
```

[Источник](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-tree-set-1-search-and-insertion/)